# Should I move offices?

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

What are the benefits of the 2nd office? The garage only has 8k upkeep but the 2nd office has 32k upkeep - is it worth moving offices?

Comment: Only if you got a big chunk of money imho

Answer (score 18):

Yes, you should, it allows you to:

- Increase the size of your dev team.
- Get better training options.
- Train specialists.
- Develop larger projects.
- Unlock the R&D lab and the Hardware lab at the second and final upgraded office.

Comment: While it unlocks a lot of things essential to progressing in the game, I believe it should only be done once it's clear you can absorb the new higher monthly cost easily.

Comment: @leokhorn, The option to move to a new office in offered to you only once you reach a certain amount of money, so that makes sure that you can make enough money.

Comment: During one of my early playthroughs I moved offices right as it was offered to me and, slowly but surely, ended up overwhelmed by the new costs. I also hired extra staff too fast. I got the feeling that too much too fast is bad, though if you know what you're doing, it may still work out.

Answer (score 2):

Yes ,moving office is very essential, not only for the benefits of game progression. For example you gain the ability to train workers which make your games better, you also get the ability to make medium and larger games, larger and medium contacts, you gain the ability to patronize publishers, it offers training which means you will progress to become a better programmer...

Answer (score 1):

I say not as soon as it offers you. I'm going through a playthrough now and it really really helped not to move until later (and I mean late) because the small upkeep allowed me to use the RP on topics and features to go into the game engine which made games. In the end I was going to move when I obtained 6M again but I made a game which took my funds through the roof so I thought why not. Currently on just over 300M :D

Answer (score 1):

What I have found is you need to, but you should wait until you have 4M or more cash and have researched 3D Graphics V2. This way, you have enough technology to pay the employees and the extra 24K upkeep.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but wait to 10 Million Moneys It will give you a buffer just in case.